# tocloft removes content title formatting

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I am using code from this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/93792/19817 to make horizontal lines above and under chapter title.

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\huge}
  {\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
  {3ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1.5ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Numbered Chapter}

\end{document}
```

However, I wanted to remove space above content title and used code from this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46863/19817.

```
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-3em}
```

`tocloft` does what I want, but it also removes horizontal lines above "content". My question is: how to use `tocloft` and keep chapter title formating?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To instruct `tocloft` *not* to affect the look of the titles of the Table of Contents, the List of Figures, and the List of Tables, load the package with the option `titles`.

A side effect of using the `titles` option is that instructions such as

```
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-3em}
```

will have no effect: after all, you're asking the package not to interfere with the look of the headers. Just use the macros of the `titlesec` package to fine-tune the look of the headers.