# table of contents vertical spacing

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, formatting, vertical-alignment

Trying to write a paper and this larger vertical white space will not go away. How do I get rid of it or at least move the list up?

The code I'm using is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

% I cut all the packages out

\section*{Table of Contents}   
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Table of Contents}  
\tableofcontents
```

I believe that is all the reliant code.

Please help, thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: found an answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46724/remove-vertical-space-before-table-of-contents-title

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove vertical space before table of contents title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46724/remove-vertical-space-before-table-of-contents-title)